# Making a time counter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, timer, counter

I am trying to make a simple game like: www.aimbooster.com to test my javascript knowledge but I have come into a problem. Basically I want to have a timer that counts the amount of time the user has got but I can't use the setInterval method because then the program has to wait a whole second before anything else happens which is not what I want. What I want is this timer process to run in the background. I think this is commonly named as "Threading". How would I go about this?. I'd want something along the lines of:

```
function startTimer() {
   while (stop == false)  {
       setInterval(function() {time++};1000);
  }
}


function startGame()  {
   startTimer();
   //MY GAME STARTS HERE

}
```

If I do this at the moment, the startTimer function will continually go and I won't be able to do anything else. I want startTimer to be a subproccess while the main process is the game.

Comment: *setTimeout* and *setInterval* have a nominal resolution of 1ms, but it may not run that quickly. Some versions of IE were 15ms or so, other browsers maybe 2 or 3ms. This is not threading, javascript is synchronous (mostly). The function passed to *setInterval* will be run at about the interval you specify, in between other javascript functions. It will not run while other javascript functions are running.

Comment: BTW, there are plenty of articles on the web on how *setTimeout* and *setInterval* work. Read a few, I'm sure some have inaccuracies but overall you'll get the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (stop === false)  {
   setInterval(function() {time++};1000);
}
```

this is a infinite loop, and you are calling setInterval infinite time and the `eventloop` doesn't have a chance to pop the callback to the stack to increase the time variable.

I would like to save the timer variable, and use clearInterval to stop the timer

```
function Game() {

}

Game.prototype.start = function() {
   this.timer = setInterval(function() {
     // do your stuff
   }, 1000);
   // start game
}

Game.prototype.stop = function() {
   clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Comment: Nearly right. *time* is incremented infinitely, the javascript engine doesn't get a breather so it is an endless loop that runs once (and nothing else gets a lookin).

Comment: THIS is exactly what I wanted. I can run my other code while having the counter going in the background. I appreciate this a lot. I don't really understand what this or prototype are so I'll have to read it up. But really thanks again for the help

Comment: @mre12345, but isn't this resource-depleting the RAM is going to be flood with numerous setInterval requests?

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
function startTimer() {
       setInterval(function() {while (stop == false) time++}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Would this run in the background though? So like I wouldn't have to wait a whole second to run my other processes?
Sorry about the bad english it's not my first language

Comment: And how do you stop this timer?

Comment: You would stop it by setting stop variable to true. So this would be when the user fails their round.

Comment: This creates an infinite loop for some reason